# Atribuindo um texto dentro de metodos JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Estou com um problema preciso inserir um texto antes do retorno de um requisição em uma `api`:

```
getSW();

function getSW() {

  $.getJSON("https://swapi.co/api/films", function (json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));

    var films = {
        f1: data.results[2],
        f2: data.results[1],
        f3: data.results[3],
        f4: data.results[0],
        f5: data.results[5],
        f6: data.results[4],
        f7: data.results[6],
    };


    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
      $("main .row").append(
      "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'>" +
      "<div class='item films'>"
         +  "<h2 class='title'>" + films["f" + i].title.toLowerCase() + "</h2>" + "<br />" +
         +  "<h1 class='title'>" + films["f" + i].director + "</h1>" +
      "<div class='crawls hidden'><div>" +
            "<h2>" + films["f" + i].title.toLowerCase() + "</h2>" +
            "<p class=''>" + films["f" + i].opening_crawl + "</p>" +
      "</div></div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");
```

Preciso inserir um texto antes de `films["f" + i]` ....

Comment: seria `>" + "Texto Aleatório" + films["f" + i]` ...

Comment: Já tentei ele nem carrega o o main ...

Comment: ta complicado saber o seu proposito, mas, de inicio o seu endereço para resgatar corretamente somente o `json`: `https://swapi.co/api/films/?format=json` ... o que precisa ser feito?

Comment: Colar um texto antes da resposta da api por exemplo +  "<h1 class='title'>" **NOME DO DIRETOR** + films["f" + i].director + "</h1>" +

Comment: Eu passei isso no primeiro comentário! agora o seu código não está dando algum erro?

Comment: Desculpe não havia visto, deu certo porém aparece como nandiretor...

Comment: Fiz um exemplo funcional logo abaixo!

Comment: Tentei aplicar a ideia sem sucesso

Comment: Não pode fazer isso aqui mas, é porque se colocou aspas simples em tudo nos internos coloque aspas duplas vai dar certo sim! aqui por exemplo deveria ser assim: `'<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">'` ou contrário: `"<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com um exemplo *simples*, você pode adicionar um **Texto Diferente**, no seu código como demonstrado logo abaixo:

```js
getSW();

function getSW() {
  $.getJSON("https://swapi.co/api/films/?format=json", function(json) {
    $("div.row").empty();
    $.each(json.results, function(i, it) {
      let text = '';
      text = text + '<div>';
      text = text + '<h4>' + 'Texto Diferente - ' + it.title + '</h4>';
      text = text + '</div>';
      text = text + '<hr/>';
      $("div.row").append(text);
    });
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"> Carregando ... </div>
```

no seu código original está muito verboso, muita escrita e conceitos errados, porque se precisa saber os `results` de forma dinâmica é só indicar o resultado do `json.results`.